# An idiomatic expression for "coordinated the meeting time"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-request, idiom-request

Imagine a boss wants to know if his secretary has arranged a coordination with the partner company; e.g. for tomorrow morning. He may ask something like:

> - Have you coordinated the meeting **time** with them?

That sounds natural grammatically and idiomatically.

- But my question is whether it is possible to substitute "time" in the above self-made sentence with the word "hour"?  Would it make any sense then?
- Is there a more idiomatic alternative?

Comment: It needs to be past tense "coordinated", since you are asking about something that has (presumably) already been done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It still makes sense grammatically, but isn't idiomatic.  It's a little ambiguous because it could also be asking if the secretary has coordinated the itinerary of the (presumably hour-long) meeting.

If you're looking for a different/idiomatic way to ask that question,  the boss might ask:

> Have you scheduled the meeting with them?